# Why convert Oswin?

Tags: doctor-who

In Parliament of the Daleks, we find out that the nano-dalek-bots have

> converted Oswin into a fully fledged Dalek

Now this is on a planet with the full dalek shielding up. Why do that, when you can't utilise her? It doesn't really make sense to me. Did they have a plan for her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The planet was essentially a prison for the insane, the battle-scarred and the uncontrollable Daleks. As far as the Dalek parliament went, they seemed to be unaware of any specifics of what went on inside the planet's shield, as it was fully automated (they didn't even have an accurate or full count of the number of Daleks on the planet.

All they knew was that they received a transmission of music from planet and had no idea what it was.

> Then The Doctor initiated communication with the person sending the transmission, who ended up being Oswin. He realized that the Oswin's crashed spaceship damaged the shield, and there was a risk of Daleks inmates getting loose out in the universe.

-

> Not wanting to go down to insane asylum themselves (the Daleks were terrified of the prospect), they "volunteered" The Doctor to go down to the planet to turn off the impenetrable shield so the Dalek ship could "cleanse" the planet from orbit.

-

> As for why the conversion to begin with, the only answers we have right now are:

-

> 1. The Daleks on the planet were insane

-

> 2. The nano-conversion process was part of the automated security measures on the planet

-

> 3. The Daleks "need genius", as the Doctor said, thus did a "full conversion" on Oswin since she was of genius-level intelligence.

It's likely that either in the Christmas special or following episodes, we'll have more answers to Oswin's fate.

Comment: So it was more of an automatic conversion?

Comment: As far as we know from the limited backstory in the episode, yes.